# ClassNotFoundException for Spark job on Yarn-cluster mode

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, apache-phoenix

So I am trying to run a Spark job on Yarn-cluster mode kicked off via Oozie workflow, but have been encountering the following error (relevant stacktrace below)

```
java.sql.SQLException: ERROR 103 (08004): Unable to establish connection.
    at org.apache.phoenix.exception.SQLExceptionCode$Factory$1.newException(SQLExceptionCode.java:388)
    at org.apache.phoenix.exception.SQLExceptionInfo.buildException(SQLExceptionInfo.java:145)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.openConnection(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:296)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.access$300(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:179)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$12.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1917)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$12.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1896)
    at org.apache.phoenix.util.PhoenixContextExecutor.call(PhoenixContextExecutor.java:77)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.init(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1896)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.getConnectionQueryServices(PhoenixDriver.java:180)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.connect(PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.java:132)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.connect(PhoenixDriver.java:151)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    ...
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:240)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager.createConnection(ConnectionManager.java:414)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager.createConnectionInternal(ConnectionManager.java:323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.createConnection(HConnectionManager.java:144)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.HConnectionFactory$HConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(HConnectionFactory.java:47)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.openConnection(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:294)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:238)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unable to find org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.controller.ClientRpcControllerFactory
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ReflectionUtils.instantiateWithCustomCtor(ReflectionUtils.java:36)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcControllerFactory.instantiate(RpcControllerFactory.java:58)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.createAsyncProcess(ConnectionManager.java:2317)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.<init>(ConnectionManager.java:688)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.<init>(ConnectionManager.java:630)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.controller.ClientRpcControllerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ReflectionUtils.instantiateWithCustomCtor(ReflectionUtils.java:32)
    ... 42 more
```

Some background information:

- The job runs on spark 1.4.1 (specified correct spark.yarn.jar field in the spark.conf file).
- oozie.libpath is set to the hdfs directory in which the jar of my program resides.
- org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.controller.ClientRpcControllerFactory, the class not found, exists in phoenix-4.5.1-HBase-1.0-client.jar. I've specified this jar in spark.driver.extraClassPath and spark.executor.extraClassPath in my spark.conf file. I've also added the phoenix-core dependency in my pom file, so that the class exists in my shaded project jar as well.

Observations so far:

- adding an extra field in my spark.conf file spark.driver.userClassPathFirst and setting it to true gets rid of the classnotfound exception. However, it also prevents me from initializing a spark context (null pointer exception). From googling around it seems that including this field messes up classpaths, so may not be the way to go about it since I cannot even initialize a spark context this way.
- I noticed that in the oozie stdout log, I do not see the classpath of the phoenix jar. So maybe for some reason spark.driver.extraClassPath and spark.executor.extraClassPath aren't actually picking up the jar as an extraClassPath? I do know that I'm specifying the correct jar file path, as other jobs have spark.conf files with the same parameters.
- I found a hacky way to make the phoenix jar show up in the classpath (in the oozie stdout log) by copying the jar to the same directory as where my program jar resides. This works whether or not spark.executor.extraClassPath is changed to point to the new jar location. However, the classnotfound exception persists, even though I clearly see the ClientRpcControllerFactory jar when I unzip the jar)

Other things I've tried:

- I tried using the sparkConf.setJars() and sparkContext.addJar() methods, but still encountered the same error
- added the jar in the spark.driver.extraClassPath field in my job properties file, but it hasn't seemed to help (Spark docs indicated that this field is necessary when running in client mode, so may not be relevant for my case)

Any help/ideas/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems that the above stated exception trace is not generated by the Spark Job. I do not see it originating from Spark classes. is it possible that Oozie workflow is also instantiating the Hbase/ Phoenix connection and that too before your spark job is launched?

Comment: If the Phoenix JAR was present in the HDFS directory that `oozie.libpath` points to, then Oozie would tell YARN to download it to the container of the Oozie Launcher, in Current Working Dir, and it would show in StdOut (both in list of files & in CLASSPATH).

Comment: `spark.***.extraClassPath` properties are managed by Spark run-time; Oozie and YARN are unaware of them, so they have no effect on initial CLASSPATH as listed in StdOut of the Oozie Launcher.

Comment: Note that Spark 1.6 ships a bunch of bug fixes related to CLASSPATH issues under YARN. Not all of them, though.

Comment: Hi Sumit, thanks for your response. I think you're right that the error is not necessarily related to this being a Spark job, as this error appears before I need to initialize a spark context. So yes this can be treated as any other classnotfound exception. What is confusing to me is that I checked the class is being loaded correctly through my application jar via the jvm option -verbose:class, and yet it complains that the class is not found.

Comment: Thanks for your response Samson. I found that you're right about the extraClassPath properties being managed at run-time. Even if it is not in the HDFS directory that oozie.libpath points to (and therefore not in the StdOut of Oozie) I can see the jar included in the current project classpath by including this code here: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-print-out-the-current-project-classpath/ And besides, one would think that the phoenix jar is not even necessary, because the not found class in question exists in my application jar as well.

Comment: 1.6 could also be an option, but not sure how easy it is to install on the cluster and have success with it. I was using 1.4.1 because it is the only version that other teams has had success with in this cloudera cluster that is bundled with 1.3.

Answer (score 0):

I use CDH 5.5.1 + Phoenix 4.5.2 (both installed with parcels) and faced the same problem. I think the problem disappeared after I switched to client mode. I can't verify this because I am getting other error with cluster mode now.

I tried to trace Phoenix source code and found some interesting things. Hope Java / Scala expert identify the root cause.

1. The `PhoenixDriver` class was loaded.
   This showed the jar was found initially. After layers of Class Loader /
   context switch (?), the jar lost from the classpath.
2. If I `Class.forName()` a non-existing class in my program, there is no need to call `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)`. The stack is like:

   ```
   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: NONEXISTINGCLASS
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
   at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
   at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
   ```
3. I copied Phoenix code into my program for testing. I still get the `ClassNotFoundExcpetion` if I call `ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.init (ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1896)`. However, a call to `ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.openConnection (ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:296)` returned usable HBase connection. So it seems `PhoenixContextExecutor` was causing the loss of the jar, but I don't know how.

Source code of Cloudera Phoenix 4.5.2 : https://github.com/cloudera-labs/phoenix/blob/phoenix1-4.5.2_1.2.0/phoenix-core/src/main/java/org/apache/

(Not sure whether I should post a comment... but I have no reputation anyway)

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to fix my issue and get my job to run. My solution is very hacky, but will post it here in case it may help others in the future.

Basically, the problem as I understand it was that the `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ReflectionUtils` class, which is responsible for finding the `ClientRpcControllerFactory` class, was being loaded from some cloudera directory in the cluster instead of from my own jar. When I set `spark.driver.userClassPathFirst` to true, it prioritized loading the ReflectionUtils class from my jar, and so was able to location the `ClientRpcControllerFactory` class. But that messed up some other classpaths and kept giving me a NullPointerException when I tried to initialize a SparkContext, so I looked for another solution.

I tried to figure out if it was possible to exclude all default cdh jars from being included in my classpath, but found that the value in spark.yarn.jar was pulling in all these cdh jars, and I definitely needed to specify that jar.

So the solution was to include all classes under `org.apache.hadoop.hbase` from the Phoenix jar into spark-assembly jar (the jar that spark.yarn.jar pointed to), which got rid of the original exception and did not give me a NPE when trying to initialize a SparkContext. I found that now the `ReflectionUtils` class was being loaded from the spark-assembly jar, and since the `ClientRpcControllerFactory`was also included in that jar, it was able to find it. After this, I encountered a few more classNotFoundExceptions for Phoenix classes, so I put those classes into the spark-assembly jar as well.

Finally, I had a `java.lang.RuntimeException: hbase-default.xml File Seems to be for and old Version of HBase` problem. I found that my application jar contained such a file, but changing `hbase.defaults.for.version.skip` to true didn't do anything. So I included another hbase-default.xml file in the spark-assembly jar with the skip flag to true, and it finally worked.

Some observations:

- I noticed that my spark-assembly jar was completely missing an org.apache.hadoop.hbase directory. A coworker told me that usually I should expect to find an hbase directory in my spark-assembly jar, so maybe I was working with a bad spark-assembly jar. Edit: I checked a spark-assembly jar that I newly downloaded (v1.5.2) and it doesn't have it, so maybe the apache.hadoop.hbase package is not included in it.
- ClassNotFoundExceptions and classloader problems are hard to debug.